# Eclipse how to disable validation for txt file (lsp4e)

Tags: eclipse

I have created a "banner.txt" file in my spring boot application to customize the banner.
Eclipse is validating it (marker is from "lsp4e") for unknown reason, i can't find an entry for text file in preferences -> validation.

The error is `Expecting a 'Map' but found a 'Scalar'`
The complete text file is marked red (it contains just ASCII art similar to spring's banner)

How to disable validating txt files?

Answer (score 10):

This seems to happen when YAML validation is applied to the text files by associating text editors with specific files. In my case there were 2 language servers that would mess things up: BOSH and Concourse (You may have more or less). The simplest way is to go to `Preferences->Language Servers` and uncheck anything that has these 2 names. Then select your file and do `Window->Show View->Problems`, right click on the error in the `Problems` view and delete it.

I'm not sure about implications of disabling these 2 language servers but I'm not interested in the files these seem to be associated with and so far haven't run into any troubles

P.S. These two (Concourse and BOSH) are part of Spring Suit installation that deal with pipelines and tasks. I ended up uninstalling these two

Comment: Uninstalling BOSH and Concourse language feature from Eclipse worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and could solve it by changing the extension to .text and restarting eclipse.